# How python subprocess can detect a negative exit code? How to force it return 0 instead?

Tags: python, suricata, pkill

I'm using pkill to send USR2 signal to suricata by python subprocess as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

script_command='pkill -SIGUSR2 -f /usr/bin/suricata'
exit_status = subprocess.call(script_command, env=self.config_environment, shell=True)
```

the result is: `exit_status = -12`

When I executed on terminal:

```
pkill -SIGUSR2 -f /usr/bin/suricata
echo $?
```

the result is: `0`

As I understand the document said at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode

Does Python detect return code of `pkill` process or `suricata` process is 12?

How can I bypass this mechanism and force `subprocess.call` return 0 when `pkill` send USR2 to suricata successfully and negative exit code corresponding to `pkill` process's feedback?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you've linked says

> A negative value `-N` indicates that the child was terminated by signal `N` (POSIX only).

This implies that the process run by `subprocess.call()` was killed by SIGUSR2 (since [`SIGUSR2` is 12](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

Since you're using `shell=True`, there will be a process with the command line `sh -c '... suricata'`, which will be matched by `pkill -f` (since `-f` means *The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command line is used.*).

You may want to do

```
ret = subprocess.call([
  shutil.which("pkill"),
  "-SIGUSR2",
  "-f",
  "/usr/bin/suricata",
])
```

to avoid the additional shell process.

Better yet, you could use e.g. [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to find the Suricata process and kill it.

## EDIT

From the comments:

> However `pkill -SIGUSR2 -F /var/run/suricata.pid` is enough

If you have a pidfile at hand, you don't need `pkill` for *anything*...

```
import os
import signal

with open("/var/run/suricata.pid", "r") as pidfile:
  pid = int(pidfile.read().strip())
  os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR2)
```

Comment: How can I force python confirm result of `pkill` not `suricata`? If `pkill ` return 0, then python should feedback me 0, and -1 if `pkill` return 1?

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Summary: `pkill` *does* return 0. However, Python doesn't start `pkill`; it starts `sh` (because of `shell=True`). Normally, the `sh` process would start `pkill`, and then report the value that the `pkill` process returned. But because of how `pkill` works, *it kills the `sh` process*. So Python sees the -12 returned because that's how the `sh` process was killed. I hope this answers the first comment.

Comment: It should also work to just *not use `-f`* for the `pkill` command, so that it only looks at the process name instead of the full command when deciding which processes to kill. After all, all the processes you want to kill have `/usr/bin/suricata` *in the process name*, right? Or do you have to kill some *other* `sh` wrappers or something?

Comment: Thank you both so much! Finally I understand that the reason is `pkill` will kill python subprocess also. I try `pkill -SIGUSR2 /usr/bin/suricata` but pkill fail with `1`. However `pkill -SIGUSR2 -F /var/run/suricata.pid` is enough to fit me, less changes to current abstract logic <3.

Comment: @NguyễnLouis Ah, you should've said you have a pidfile. See my edit...